# Github action that push to another branch?

Tags: github-actions

I've created a Github action that is triggered when I push a code to the "staging" branch. The action runs the tests, and when successful, I'd like it to push the code from staging to the "prod" branch.

I can't make this work. What I'm doing wrong?

Here's my Github action :

```yaml
name: Test and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'
          cache: 'pip' # caching pip dependencies

      - name: Start Redis
        uses: supercharge/redis-github-action@1.5.0

      - name: Update pip
        run: pip install --upgrade pip

      - name: Install requirements.txt
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Install test requirements
        run: pip install pytest pytest-cov sanic-testing==22.12.0 aiosqlite==0.18.0

      - name: Test with pytest
        run: pytest tests

  deploy:
    needs: test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Deploy to prod
        run: |
          git push -u origin prod
```

The above command yields the following error:

> error: src refspec prod does not match any
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myproject/repo'

If I do `git checkout -b prod` first,  I get the following error:

> Switched to a new branch 'prod'
> From https://github.com/myproject/repo
>
> - branch            prod       -> FETCH_HEAD
> - [new branch]      prod       -> origin/prod
>   fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

I also tried:

> Run git checkout -b prod   git checkout -b prod   git pull origin prod
> git push -u origin prod   shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0} Switched to a
> new branch 'prod' From https://github.com/myproject/repo  * branch
> prod       -> FETCH_HEAD  * [new branch]      prod       ->
> origin/prod hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how
> to reconcile them. hint: You can do so by running one of the following
> commands sometime before hint: your next pull: hint:  hint:   git
> config pull.rebase false  # merge hint:   git config pull.rebase true
>
> ## rebase hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only hint:  hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global"
>
> to set a default hint: preference for all repositories. You can also
> pass --rebase, --no-rebase, hint: or --ff-only on the command line to
> override the configured default per hint: invocation. fatal: Need to
> specify how to reconcile divergent branches. Error: Process completed
> with exit code 128.

And

> git checkout -b prod   git push -u origin prod   shell:
> /usr/bin/bash -e {0} Switched to a new branch 'prod' To
> https://github.com/myproject/repo  ! [rejected]        prod -> prod
> (fetch first) error: failed to push some refs to
> 'https://github.com/myproject/repo' hint: Updates were rejected
> because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally.
> This is usually caused by another repository pushing hint: to the same
> ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g.,
> 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about
> fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: I believe you want to merge staging into production. Here is some inspiration: https://medium.com/@karlstad/create-a-github-actions-workflow-that-auto-merges-the-master-back-to-dev-branch-8b1ebe7009b3

Comment: Thank you, that's a good approach. The only issue is that I now have "prod" (the branch I checked out) that is 1 commit ahead of staging (the branch I triggered the action). Do you know why?

Comment: I guess you need to check latest commit in prod-branch to see what it is about. It might be that `rebase` is more appropriate for your case in order to move the staging-branch to the tip of the prod-branch as explained here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing